# Victoria Metrics - Delete time series with missing label

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

I using a Victoria Metrics cluster.
I have two timeseries that differ because one is missing a label.
My question is how to delete the one with the missing label ?
I see that I can use a time series selectors list for the match[] value, but how to select a time series with a missing label ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to query for the missing label using !="some_label_value_that_doesnt_exist" like in the following example:

```
some_metric{missing_label!="xxxxx"}
```

All time-series without the missing_label should be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `match[]` series selector:

```
some_metric{missing_label=''}
```

It should return all the time series with `some_metric` name but without `missing_label` label.

Note that it is always good idea to check which time series will be deleted before actually deleting them. This can be done by passing the constructed `match[]` query arg to  [/api/v1/series](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#finding-series-by-label-matchers) handler.